# Use Jquery with the div of a data result of a post ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have this post code in a one.jsp

```
$.post("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/two.jsp", {
            vaedre: fullDate}
         ,function(result){
           $("#theresult").append(result);
          });
```

And it generate in one.jsp:

```
<div id="theresult">
<div id="kily"></div>
</div>
```

If I try to use this jquery code, that is in one.jsp it doesnt work:

```
$('#kily').click(function() {
alert("this is a test");
});
```

I think that is beacuse the div kily is in two.jsp but not in one.jsp altought it seems to be in one.jsp after the append.

Any help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Which is the console error?

Comment: try using `.on('click', function...` instead of `.click`

Comment: No error in the console. It doesnt recognice the <div id="kily"></div> I think so it doesnt execute the javascript

Comment: Java is not the JavaScript.

Comment: Javascript code its ok if I put it together it works, but as the <div id="kily"></div> comes from two.jsp it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Either us
.   $(document)on('click', '#kily', function(){});

or create your click event after you append the element

Comment: no, $(document)on('click', '#kily', funtion(){}); doesnt work

Comment: My apologies, on cell phone

Comment: I meant $(document).on('click', '#kily', function(){});